# Pandas df to SQL Server, connecting without user/password

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

I'm currently trying to write a pandas data frame into a new SQL Server table, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to connect WITHOUT USING USER/PASSWORD.

Pandas documentation states that an engine must be created via sqlalchemy, and the company only gave me a sample code (not using pandas, for other tasks) for the connection via pymssql:

```
    server = "server name"

    conn = pymssql.connect(server, database='TestDatabase') 

    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute(instruction)

    conn.close()
```

Now I must pass a connection to sqlalchemy, which the sqlalchemy documentation states would be something like

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pymssql://<username>:<password>@<freetds_name>/?charset=utf8",
                            encoding='latin1', echo=True)
```

but our SQL Server instance uses local authentication, and I found no model for this.

How can I create this connection string?